# JPA Error: ID class should not be mapped

Tags: java, jpa

I have JPA code that compiles fine in eclipse Helios and works fine in production. But in a newer version of eclipse, I am getting the error "ID class should not be mapped" when using the annotation @IdClass from javax.persistence.* package.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(RetailLocationPK.class)  // Generates "ID class should not be mapped" error
@Table(name="loc_rtl_loc")
public class RetailLocation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="organization_id")    
    private int organizationId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="rtl_loc_id")
    private int rtlLocId;
...
}
```

Then in RetailLocationPK.java I have:

```
@Embeddable
public class RetailLocationPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="organization_id")
    private int organizationId;

    @Column(name="rtl_loc_id")
    private int rtlLocId;

    public RetailLocationPK() {
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, in persistence.xml, I have:

```
<persistence-unit name="taxPu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <class>tbss.persist.RetailLocation</class>
    <class>tbss.persist.RetailLocationPK</class>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

I have turned off the error notification for now, but why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it shouldn't be, but `@IdClass` (unlike `@EmbeddedId`) definitely doesn't have to be `@Embeddable` and mapped with `<class>`.

Comment: I removed the @Embeddable from the PK class and also removed its <class> element from the persistence.xml file and the error went away. Now to test it.